# Iterating through list and make sequential network calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

How do i iterate through a list and make sequential network calls using a sdk?
I am trying to use Coinbase's Node sdk and get the first 10 transactions for all accounts.

I have a list of accounts, and i iterating through them and calling client.account, client.transactions, and client.transactions(pagination). And im adding the results to an array of transactions and returning that array.

I couldn't get this to work with async/await or request-promises.
Any ideas?

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#transactions

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var coinbase = require('coinbase');
var client = new coinbase.Client({ 'apiKey': 'keyStuff', 'apiSecret': 'secretStuff' });
var accountList = ['acct1','acct2','acct3',];
var transactionList = [];


try {
        let ps = [];
        accountList.forEach(acctId => {
            var account = client.getAccount(accountId, null);
            ps.push(rp(account));
        });
        Promise.all(ps)
            .then(responses => {
                for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
                    var result = responses[i];
                    rp(result.account.getTransactions(null))
                        .then(res => {
                            res.pagination = 10;
                            return rp(result.account.getTransactions(null, res.pagination));
                        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
                        .then(txns => {
                            try {
                                if (txns.length > 0) {
                                    txns.forEach(function(txn) {
                                            var transaction = {
                                                "trade_type": "",
                                                "price": ""
                                            };
                                            transaction.trade_type = txn.type;
                                            transaction.price = txn.native_amount.amount;
                                            transactionList.push(transaction);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            catch (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });
                }

            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        return transactionList;

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        // if (accountList.length > 0) {

        //     for (let acctId of accountList) {
        //         console.log("account id: " + acctId);
        //         await delayTransactions(acctId);
        //     }

        //     console.log("got here last");
        //     return transactionList;
        // }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

The commented-out delay method has nested async calls like this:

```
await client.getAccount(accountId, async function(err, account) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
else {
    await account.getTransactions(null, async function(err, txns, pagination) {
.
.
.
```

Comment: please add some code what you already try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using async/await and promises. awaiting the coinbase methods wouldn't work because they aren't async functions (surprise!).

```
function delayedMethod() {
    new Promise(resolve => {
    client.getAccount(accountId, async function(err, account) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        account.getTransactions(null, async function(err, txns, pagination) {
    .
    .
    .
    resolve();
    });
}
```